# UIButton not reacting to first press in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am working on a simple (ok, it should be simple) calculator that estimates risk based on a few inputs (toggle on/off)

Everything is working properly, except that the UIButtons need to be tapped 2 times to toggle initially.  After that, the UIButtons work as expected.

Here is the code (contained within viewDidLoad())

```
@IBOutlet weak var confusionButton: UIButton!

var counter = 0

var confusionToggle = 0
```

and here is the action

```
@IBAction func pressConfusion(sender: UIButton) {

        if confusionToggle == 0 {

            confusionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            confusionButton.alpha = 1;
            confusionToggle++;
            counter++;
        } else {
            confusionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            confusionButton.alpha = 0.5;
            confusionToggle = 0
            counter--;
        }




    }
```

Any thoughts on this one?  My Swift skills are very limited (my first attempt with Swift)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you trying to do.

Just let you know that `confusionToggle` will be 0 at first time. So, when you click on the button your first condition will be called, It will clear the background color and increase the value of `confusionToggle` to 1 then after it's because of 1 it will not go to the first condition. So, it goes to else part and give the background color to the gray. `confusionToggle` again goes to 0.

And it will iterate every time like 0 - 1 - 0 - 1 ...

If you want to do gray color to the button when you tap then you have to change your logic.

```
    if confusionToggle == 0 {
        confusionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        confusionButton.alpha = 0.5;
        confusionToggle = 1;
        counter++;
    } else {
        confusionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        confusionButton.alpha = 1;
        confusionToggle = 0
        counter--;
    }
```

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

Think your just getting yourself confused. Use print statements to first understand what is happening, then do all your fancy button UI changes.

```
@IBAction func tapButton(sender: UIButton) {

    // user println to help debug
    println(confusionToggle)

    if confusionToggle == 0 {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        sender.alpha = 0.5;
        confusionToggle++;
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        // RESET
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        sender.alpha = 1;
        confusionToggle = 0
        counter--;
    }
}
```